# jquery cycle slideshow with text underneath

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I have a simple slideshow of images using the jquery cycle script.

I'm trying to place description text to appear UNDER the slides of images - but it doesn't seem to be possible - any ideas?

here's the test page: http://jsfiddle.net/cjaM5/

You can see the description text flashing after the 3rd image in the slides.

I've tried display block etc., but still can't get it working. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/nNWVS/

I added the description to the innermost div's as i'm guessing the description will be unique to each image.

Comment: thanx- It would really just be be 1 paragraph of text or a postmetadata line like :
posted in: illustration, design, work etc., 

rather than a description for each image

Comment: Are you able to give `#slides` a height?

Comment: The images might be different heights as I'm plugging it into wordpress.